# SOQl Injection Checkmarx issues

Tags: soql, checkmarx, soql-injection

I am getting SOQL Injection checkmarx issue even after applying escapeSingleQuotes. Can you pls tell what should I apply to remove checkmarx issue.
Here is Code

```java
public static Interaction__c GetInteractionByID(Id InteractionId)   {

        String Interactionquery = 'SELECT Id, Name,Provider_ID__c, Interaction_Type__c, Originator_Type__c FROM Interaction__c WHERE Id =:InteractionId';
        
        Interaction__c Interaction = database.query(String.escapeSingleQuotes(Interactionquery));
        return Interaction;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using variable binding, it's a false positive.
Indeed, as stated in this trailhead about [Mitigate SOQL Injection](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/it/content/learn/modules/secure-serverside-development/mitigate-soql-injection#soql-injection-prevention)

> The first and most recommended method to prevent SOQL injection is to use static queries with bind variables

Anyway here you don' need a dynamic query, so to remove the warning you could use a static one:

```java
public static Interaction__c GetInteractionByID(Id InteractionId)   {
    Interaction__c Interaction = [SELECT Id, Name, Provider_ID__c, Interaction_Type__c, Originator_Type__c FROM Interaction__c WHERE Id =:InteractionId];
    return Interaction;
}
```

By the way, you should always prefer static queries over dynamic ones. They would also check for typos in fields or object names, and if any, it would give an error at deploy time.